# Let's golf a BIBABOBU decoder

Tags: code-golf, string, hexadecimal

While I was traveling in the future, I noticed a funny game among kids circa 2275. When they don't want their great-great-great-great-grand parents to understand what they're saying, they use the ***BIBABOBU speak***. Obviously, I couldn't understand anything either with my pre-cyborg era brain and I felt (or technically: *I will feel*) really silly. So, I'd need a decoder for my next visit.

### BIBABOBU?

While it's been deprecated for a long time, ASCII is still commonly used in the pop culture of 2275 and this language is based upon it.

A string is BIBABOBU-encoded that way:

- Convert all characters to their ASCII codes.
- Take the 2-digit hexadecimal representation of each code and convert them using the following table:

  ```
  0: BI  4: BIDI  8: BADI  C: BODI
  1: BA  5: BIDA  9: BADA  D: BODA
  2: BO  6: BIDO  A: BADO  E: BODO
  3: BU  7: BIDU  B: BADU  F: BODU
  ```

#### Example

```
"Hello!" → 48 65 6C 6C 6F 21 → "BIDIBADI BIDOBIDA BIDOBODI BIDOBODI BIDOBODU BOBA"
```

However, the corresponding **input** would be given without any space to mimic the monotonous intonation that kids are using to make this even harder to understand without implants:

```
"BIDIBADIBIDOBIDABIDOBODIBIDOBODIBIDOBODUBOBA"
```

### Clarifications and rules

- Remember that I need a ***decoder***, not an encoder.
- Decoded characters are guaranteed to be in the range **[ 32...126 ]**.
- The input is guaranteed to contain en even number of BIBABOBU-encoded hexadecimal digits.
- You may take input in either full lowercase or full uppercase. Mixed cases are not allowed.
- Because bit flips are quite common during a time travel, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) in order to minimize the risks.

### Test cases

NB: Linefeeds are used below for formatting purposes only. You are *not* supposed to handle them.

```
Input:
BIDABIDIBIDOBIDABIDUBUBIDUBIDI

Output:
Test

Input:
BIDABIDUBIDOBIDABIDOBODIBIDOBUBIDOBODUBIDOBODABIDOBIDABOBIBIDUBIDIBIDOBODUBOBIBUBOBUBOBUBI
DUBUBIDABOBA

Output:
Welcome to 2275!

Input:
BIDIBADIBIDOBIDABIDOBODIBIDOBODIBIDOBODUBOBODIBOBIBIDABIDIBIDOBADABIDOBODABIDOBIDABOBIBIDA
BIDIBIDUBOBIDOBABIDUBIDOBIDOBIDABIDOBODIBIDOBIDABIDUBOBOBABOBIBIDABADABIDOBODUBIDUBIDABOBI
BIDOBODIBIDOBODUBIDOBODUBIDOBADUBOBIBIDUBUBIDOBODUBOBIBIDOBIDOBIDUBIDABIDOBODOBIDOBODOBIDU
BADABOBA

Output:
Hello, Time Traveler! You look so funny!

Input:
BIDIBABIDOBODOBIDOBIDIBOBIBIDUBADABIDOBODUBIDUBIDABOBIBIDOBIDIBIDOBODUBIDOBODOBOBIDUBIDUBI
DIBOBIBIDUBIDABIDOBODOBIDOBIDIBIDOBIDABIDUBOBIDUBUBIDUBIDIBIDOBABIDOBODOBIDOBIDIBOBIBIDUBI
DUBIDOBADIBIDOBABIDUBIDIBOBIBIDIBADABOBIDUBIDOBODABOBIBIDUBUBIDOBABIDUBADABIDOBADABIDOBODO
BIDOBIDUBOBODIBOBIBIDOBIDIBIDOBODUBOBIBIDUBADABIDOBODUBIDUBIDABUBODUBOBIBIDIBADIBIDOBABOBI
BIDOBADIBIDOBABOBIBIDOBADIBIDOBABOBA

Output:
And you don't understand what I'm saying, do you? Ha ha ha!
```

Comment: I like the challenge, but I would have liked it _slightly_ better if the encoding was lexicographically sorted.

Comment: @StewieGriffin These damn kids are mischievous... :-/

Comment: By the way, I find the story really really unlikely! I wouldn't be surprised if it was just a dream you had... might you have a CO leak in your house?

Comment: Ah... That would also explain the ponies riding rainbows in my living room!

Comment: "Because bit flips are quite common during a time travel" - err shouldn't it be radiation-hardened then?

Comment: Do you need a decoder for the actual BIBABOBU speak, or just for the written down version?

Comment: @MrLister The written down version is fine. :)

Comment: ... but not nearly as great a challenge.

Comment: @MrLister That would be another kettle of fish indeed. [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37160/58563) is the only voice decoding challenge I've been able to find.

Comment: One could argue that golfed code increases the severity of a bit-flip (less redundancy within the code) even if it decreases the frequency of a bit-flip... but whatever :) - Nice challenge!

Comment: @JayCe True. I was more thinking along the lines: the smaller the code, the more redundancy you can get by storing multiple copies.

Comment: ^ Of course... this makes sense.

Comment: Of course, this implies that immortality will be invented circa or before 2125.

Comment: @JonathanAllan If that solves the problem, then those bit flips would be pretty weird, since they would always restrict themselves to one byte.

Comment: Sorry, I want to like this challenge, but the premise of the question is clearly ridiculous. ASCII will never be deprecated.

Comment: It is bugging me that the encoding table is not a Huffman tree (properly organized to use the shortest phonemes for the most common symbols, of course).

Comment: I’m pretty sure that **technically** you _willan on-when presooning on-feelenta silly_ in this situation; the correct tense to use here is surely the Future Subinverted Plagal Retropast.

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 33 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Mr.Xcoder*
Saved 2 bytes thanks to *KevinCruijssen*

```
ć©¡®ì®D…IAO©â'D«‚˜®'U«âJskh2ôJHçJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SPuhlYcWHlp3eM2hdS6PGpZ5OvofWnl4kbrLodWPGmadnnNonXroodWHF3kVZ2cYHd7i5XF4udf//06eLp5OjkDs6eIPxI5g2h/KR9ChThAeUA1UFUTGEa7DEW4CqhqQTrBKMBuiBtMmCB9sixPCBITpoVDdMDlUtyHTjhAbwepDkVzviWR3KJL9/kh0KNhGoBkA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##fVIxbgIxEOzvFYiGBpo8INKershes9U@IJEiJUqRAikSEgUdf4jSQAFCRFelR7LT5Rd85DgfXtuLCYXt83puZna079PHp9fndv4xa3@XZmdWprHfpqmOiw0CmZ1djyqzPy4@/75MM2Kzt@t6@vZyZ3/qB7ut29nQHgaT@4E9FMNxW2IF3cJukf/mkvu9qxahFJ@pJA9nf5MTAqrbhSJgXM3t5yUyDgtFDwTlIsqQInG3M330DeGPSwuC6eUdMmkmV5JmyZkKDJFdcpE37S09wTcsbcYIojYn@pSc3CvGWBQEQ/t80xhmxqgUUVYslyYwC0ONRIjxuicMAaAKXBDom8NkanRQoHqDzJ0eAspm7L9kOEFg4k94blfgBA)

**Explanation**

```
ć©¡                                 # extract the head ("B") and split input on it
   ®ì                              # prepend "B" to each
     ®D                            # push 2 copies of "B"
       …IAO©â                      # cartesian product with "IAO"
             'D«                   # append "D" to each
                ‚˜                 # add the leftover "B" to the list
                  ®'U«â            # cartesian product with "IAOU"
                       J           # join each to string
                        sk         # get the index of each word of the input in this list
                          h        # convert each to hex
                           2ôJ     # format as pairs of chars
                              H    # convert to int
                               çJ  # convert from ascii-codes to string
```

Comment: I believe `'B©¡¦®ì®D…IAO©â'D«‚˜®'U«âJskh2ôJHçJ` works for 35 bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Ah, of course. Nice reuse of `©`. Thanks :)

Comment: -2 bytes changing the leading `'B` to `ć` and removing the `¦`, since the input will always start with a 'B'.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Ooh, good idea. I hadn't considered `ć`. Thanks!

Comment: Now let's get back at those kids and see if they understand that !

Comment: Grrr... you beat me by 2. Oh, and I did the challenge wrong, so, in reality, by 7. I never stood a chance xD.

Comment: So we now have a partial traduction of [THE magical song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo).. What does 
Bibbidi-bobbidi, bibbidi-bobbidi, bibbidi-bobbidi-boo.  really mean?

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>26</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> <s>20</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
ṣḢO^1%9%4Ḅḅ⁴b⁹Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVIxDsIwDNx5RZc@AImF0RGLJ08ZWBiQWBAfYCwCsfAKWBkZijrykvQjoQlxEjfAkKRxrnfnk7eb3W5vrXneTHul1bSe1zPTHk176pvHum@eprtY0z2q17k/3KultQoXMCwcFoVvrbTfh@okltIzKQpwHW58QkQNO1NEjKu5/bNYxmFh4oEgXCQZEiTu9qFPviH@MbbAGC/vkFkzpRI3S85UZEjsnAu/SW/5CaFhbjNFkLR1pk/Zqb1iikVAMLav/xrDwhgpFtWCZWwCizDESMQYv3vCGACKwBmBoTnMpkYGBaI3KNzJIaBixn4lozMEZv6Y538F3g)

#### How it works

```
ṣḢO^1%9%4Ḅḅ⁴b⁹Ọ  Main link. Argument: s (string)

 Ḣ               Head; remove and yield the first character of s.
ṣ                Split s at occurrences of the result ('B').
  O              Ordinal; map "IAOUD" to A1 := [73, 65, 79, 85, 68].
   ^1            Bitwise XOR 1; map A1 to A2 := [72, 64, 78, 84, 69].
     %9          Modulo 9; map A2 to A3 := [0, 1, 6, 3, 6].
       %4        Modulo 4; map A3 to A4 := [0, 1, 2, 3, 2].
                 So far, we've mapped "BX" to [x] and "BXDY" to [x, 2, y],
                 where x/y = 0, 1, 2, 3 when X/Y = I, A, O, U.
         Ḅ       Unbinary; map [x] to x and [x, 2, y] to 4x + 2×2 + y = 4(x + 1) + y.
          ḅ⁴     Convert the resulting array from base 16 to integer.
            b⁹   Convert the resulting integer to base 256.
              Ọ  Unordinal; replace code points with their characters.
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 58 bytes

```perl6
{S:g{(B.[D.]?)**2}=chr :16[$0».&{:2[.ords»³X%87 X%4]}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtgqvVrDSS/aRS/WXlNLy6jWNjmjSMHK0CxaxeDQbj21aiujaL38opTiQ7sPbY5QtTBXiFA1ia2Nrf1fnFipkKahEq@pkJZfpGDD5eTp4unkCMSeLv5A7Aim/aF8BB3q5O/kyAVVgKw41CkUTAJFueBC2MwKhZsEoR3hqoAkzAgk2zydQCQEw6xxBLvCzvo/AA)

Heavily inspired by Dennis' Jelly solution. Uses a different magic function `x³ % 87 % 4` which also maps the ASCII codes of `IAOUBD` to `012302`.

#### Alternative <s>75</s> 74 bytes version

*-1 byte thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
{pack('H',.trans((<B BID BAD BOD>X~ <I A O U>)=>(^16)».base(16))).decode}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5NC4JAEL37K@YQuQshdPFQJuzioT3taaFTsekKUamoQRL1x7r1x2z8zEMD772Z4fFmMpNf3PpWGDD3zOSnq0lKfYFVpsPz2rpWMI9hUz@akdhbe@GUuU4KQjwOXATAGUIG/u4FngAGEpRPNz7ZL136eTtHXRiCLaVOZMI0Ms@60BXEZHagEKc5eBamCEwRqBLBWpX9/FPFJWdWb5iaFVct49YaV/@y1JjUKRtdyEPE5JrgDXcYzrD2Cx@w6i8)

#### Alternative 85 bytes version

```perl6
{S:g[....]=chr :4(~$/)*2+|221+^:4(~$/)+^238}o{TR:d/UIAOBD/0123/}o{S:g[B.<![D]>]=0~$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtgqPVoPCGJtkzOKFKxMNOpU9DW1jLRrjIwMteOgfO04I2OL2vzqkCCrFP1QT0d/Jxd9A0MjY32gGMgAJz0bxWiXWLtYWwOg8tr/xYmVCmkaKvGaCmn5RQo2XE6eLp5OjkDs6eIPxI5g2h/KR9ChTv5OjlxQBciKQ51CwSRQlAsuhM2sULhJENoRrgpIwoxAss3TCURCMMwaR7Ar7Kz/AwA)

Comment: How about [`(^16)>>.base(16)`](https://tio.run/##bU6xCsIwEN3zFTeITUAKLh1sG0joYKZMAScl2hTEaktTwSL66/WsWh08eO/dHY93V7umjPqzd@AutWv2R3dqbQmL2u4OMTl2MC0g7a/PkQbLYBa2jT15ShMJUmUgBUJnfHWHRIEADYazlNP1PGKch1vrHcWWsTB3uyp3tz4m3nZQ0MmGQVE1kBDMUZijUDVCDKrf81eN1FKQt@HXbKQZGLdkXP3LMmPSS8XoQv5E/FxT8skvfM6I4QseE8DqHw) for -1 byte

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>100</s> <s>97</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to ovs</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to G B</sup>

```python
lambda w:''.join(' 1023546798abdcef'[int(c,35)/7%77%18]for c in w.split('B')[1:]).decode("hex")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVM9b4MwEN35FRZSZJAiWpKmpEgZbGXx5MkTzUD4UKhSQAEp7a@n2GBjhyTqYB8Hj3vvnu7q3/ZUlasu33125/j7mMbgGkLofVVF6UDgv67Wm7f34GMbH9Mky2FUlK2TLNcb9yVYBMHC3x7y6gISUJTg6jX1uWgdiKEb@eHB9dIsqdLMsU/Zj@12bda0DdiBCNiY7AlG/SF72h8kIh3zKTJMMbKXlj1idDzDTNz9Ww3B7lZkqt4QkUL1t6yicRLM7@FIJqRp@a92ng0Mk3qk/rhVITFCAUdq/cyZZL@U61IVpurSHfnN1KZHNPYsO51cmLiZxk@1yASj4YyBIsoB9lQbmWmjWPIyo8qtDjLzw5gN5eR9TUR5QAzPJYKM/RFtdkyvkNEbmqkz54DOJu2RM0xDEE2frPP8DbIPFl9MvnN8N8XuhRaoL/0Ci0w@5w7PXJlC2P0B)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands) (legacy), <s>68</s> <s>65</s> <s>60</s> 59 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•5Ç¿ÆΓ•2ô.•1ÒKá ¸ΓìŸÆt`ô_zTºγ„KRI‰ιë†½òι•4ô«I¬©¡®ìkh2ôJHçJ
```

Input is in lowercase.

-3 bytes implicitly thanks to *@Emigna* changing `'b¡εg>}s£` to `'b©¡®ì`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fVC9CsIwEH4Vn0Cs2HfwZxN3Tajg4ZDFLk6ddLe7qIuIRUQ7qCDCHa55iL5ITZv@UuyQSy7fz31Jy2TcmIZhM3AOJq3xQyvpqnOb/OjKoM2A9g18SJe874NWiwn54@UIX/IeONvBsBc4V/mkc@Ds8E03@VSiDvl47qGHJ9zjhbz5TLn1u3TshyEHCzhTVXChFsQLuKpqtzmzUsyOe1C9xjQvx7ReJCy75AJWdYLeWYxrVa6LsP@ZIJnHCsziPIhTi4wnssx6RqpI38Yq6aJEIvMrv7TuZ@wCAwr5Up/6G/YD) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##jVI9SwNBEO3zKyS1BBO8vyAm6UKw1VkiOFhs4zZWV8Xe9GJsRHKI6BWJIMIOtvcj7o@cex@zH7kYLHbndu7te28eexSB6F8W0Um36OXxU0R3@pvm2cJ8DygtW326H9PyQK@zBSU/a5rfXFB6fjvVn9lHHj@MJ8M8fss2tMrjR/1F79nGXDqmVK@GOtEveqlfKbm@MmyjU3oeFd3e2WEhcIYCzMKZNAuqKpuzq0pIAZ0G4IOVUNVuuh3b2sWlLFNdwaLMzhSeGopyrxfLALv4r@XyVNM732BvbFtgTCVfIr1h2ko8rCxNWQbHzrnwv9CbX6EZmMd0ETht5elLr6pK0cUSQNCOr/Yaw5YxKVhUBSzbJrAVRvAkbIy7PaENAIPAGYHNcOi9mjAoCGaDlrvwEcjWG/srGeUh0PPHPPs78As).

<s>Also, can definitely be golfed with something smarter than the huge compressed strings. Will take another look later on.</s> [Shorter answer already provided by *@Emigna*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171401/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

**Explanation:**

```
.•5Ç¿ÆΓ•      # Compressed string "bibabobu"
        2ô    # Split in parts of 2
              #  → ["bi","ba","bo","bu"]
.•1ÒKá ¸ΓìŸÆt`ô_zTºγ„KRI‰ιë†½òι•
              # Compressed string "bidibidabidobidubadibadabadobadubodibodabodobodu"
        4ô    # Split in parts of 4
              #  → ["bidi","bida","bido","bidu","badi","bada","bado","badu","bodi","boda","bodo","bodu"]
«             # Merge both lists together
              #  → ["bi","ba","bo","bu","bidi","bida","bido","bidu","badi","bada","bado","badu","bodi","boda","bodo","bodu"]
I¬©¡          # Take the input and split on the head (always 'b')
              #  i.e. "bidibadibidobidabidobodibidobodibidoboduboba"
              #   → ["idi","adi","ido","ida","ido","odi","ido","odi","ido","odu","o","a"]
    ®ì        # And prepend a 'b' to each item again
              #  i.e. ["idi","adi","ido","ida","ido","odi","ido","odi","ido","odu","o","a"] 
              #   → ["bidi","badi","bido","bida","bido","bodi","bido","bodi","bido","bodu","bo","ba"]
k             # Map each item to the index of the first list
              #   i.e. ["bidi","badi","bido","bida","bido","bodi","bido","bodi","bido","bodu","bo","ba"]
              #    → [4,8,6,5,6,12,6,12,6,15,2,1]
 h            # Convert everything to hexadecimal
              #  i.e. [4,8,6,5,6,12,6,12,6,15,2,1]
              #   → ["4","8","6","5","6","C","6","C","6","F","2","1"]
  2ôJ         # Split it in parts of 2 and join them together
              #  i.e. ["4","8","6","5","6","C","6","C","6","F","2","1"]
              #   → ["48","65","6C","6C","6F","21"]
     H        # Convert that from hexadecimal to an integer
              #  i.e. ["48","65","6C","6C","6F","21"] → [72,101,108,108,111,33]
      ç       # And take its ASCII value
              #  i.e. [72,101,108,108,111,33] → ["H","e","l","l","o","!"]
       J      # Then join everything together (and output implicitly)
              #  i.e. ["H","e","l","l","o","!"] → "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>88 86</s> 84 bytes

```perl6
{S:g{B(.*?)B(.D.|.)}=chr :16[$/.map:{first :k,~$_,("",|<ID AD OD UD>X~ <I A O U>)}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNa8MwDD3Pv0KUUpIRMnbpIWs7HHzRyYdhGIwxSmm2snYryS4lTf96FqeRP@qtB8mx/KL39NB@XW6n7e4AkwLm0NZP2XudR@ntY9xlkR7TuJmvPkrI7qcv47t0t9xndbEpqx/IPpPT@C2JRqPkOEMBXIAUoMTi@QQzBA4S1CJuXpuWFd8lRNvN17qKoWY31fIA6aR4YA1rcxS8C@xCDt8qV33uqsyU7LPM5QBXw41OblBdphYGo2s6n4NoNJazHsg9FZZGek307dze6ubmj0sJhOnpNdIZJmSiYaUWZTrY7uQLvfna3JMPA9OY1gLLrRx@6ZyqZ7S2eBA046urwjAQJnMiVV6XSxEYmOGthLHxb01oDEDPcELgMBw6W@Mbxb3ZeKDOXwIZ7Nh/zigHgY4@6nO9wn8B)

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p, 67 bytes

```perl
for$p(<{B,0D,1D,2D}{I,A,O,U}>){s/$p/chr$i+48/ge;$i++}$_=pack'H*',$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0ilQMOm2knHwEXH0EXHyKW22lPHUcdfJ7TWTrO6WF@lQD85o0glU9vEQj891RrI0K5VibctSEzOVvfQUtdRif//38nTxRGIQ4HYH8r2d/J38QTToVAejHaEqwKSUF2ecDUgMRAJwSDZUKhax3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, <s>43</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

Unsurprisingly,  a port of [Dennis' Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171415/58974) works out much shorter.

Outputs an array of characters.

```
Åqbu)®¬®c ^1 %9%4Ãì2Ãò ®ìG d
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xXFidSmurmMgXjEgJTklNMOs7DLD8iCu7EcgZA==&input=IkJJREFCSURVQklET0JJREFCSURPQk9ESUJJRE9CVUJJRE9CT0RVQklET0JPREFCSURPQklEQUJPQklCSURVQklESUJJRE9CT0RVQk9CSUJVQk9CVUJPQlVCSURVQlVCSURBQk9CQSIKLVA=)

---

### Original, 42 bytes

```
Åqb £`bbidbad¾d`ò3n)ï`ia`q)m¬bXibÃò ®ìG d
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xXFiIKNgYmJpZGJhZL5kYPIzbinvYGlhjGBxKW2sYlhpYsPyIK7sRyBk&input=ImJpZGFiaWR1Ymlkb2JpZGFiaWRvYm9kaWJpZG9idWJpZG9ib2R1Ymlkb2JvZGFiaWRvYmlkYWJvYmliaWR1YmlkaWJpZG9ib2R1Ym9iaWJ1Ym9idWJvYnViaWR1YnViaWRhYm9iYSIKLVA=)

#### Explanation

```
Åqb £`bbidbad¾d`ò3n)ï`ia`q)m¬bXibÃò ®ìG d
Å                                              :Slice off the first character
 qb                                            :Split on "b"
    £                                          :Map
     `bbidbad¾d`                               :  Compressed string "bbidbadbod"
                ò3n)                           :  Partition at every 3rd character from the end (["b","bid","bad","bod"])
                    ï                          :  Cartesian product
                     `ia`                      :   Compressed string "iaou"
                          q                    :   Split
                           )                   :  End Cartesian product
                            m                  :  Map
                             ¬                 :   Join
                              b                :  Index of
                               X               :   Current element
                                ib             :   Prepend "b"
                                  Ã            :End map
                                   ò           :Partition at every second element
                                     ®         :Map
                                      ìG       :  Convert from base-16 digit array to base-10 integer
                                         d     :  Get the character at that codepoint
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>141</s> 135 bytes

```r
function(x,y="I":"A":"O")intToUtf8(matrix(match(el(strsplit(gsub("D","",x),"B"))[-1],paste0(rep("":y,e=4),y:"U"))-1,,2,T)%*%16:1)
":"=c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1PC4JAEMXvfYoYEGZihIyIkDwoXjztxT1FBxMtwVTcFfTT21pqHd6bP/xmXjvm24s95l2V6qKusOfBgwhc8I0EUFHpuJY6P@Mr0W3RTyV9Ylai0q1qykLjQ3V3hBAYgHtiCIDoajs3bhKlsz22WYMA7sCZdyQeXJAGsB3mA8dk7Szn5Dq0MXFeOuYIQRT6RpGRmHsZyI@bLdDmx8g/RgRivpHztFR/pYwvf1Zm2k3@1ZI1sT7Q@AY)

*Thanks to [JayCe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80010/jayce) for saving 6 bytes!*

Using some modular magic is likely to be shorter, but I'm pretty happy with this as a naive first pass.

Comment: Nice ! My favorite trick [saves 6 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY1PC4JAEMXvfYoYEGZihIyIkDwoXjztxT1FBxMtwVTcFfTT21pqHd6bP/xmXjvm24s95l2V6qKusOfBgwhc8I0EUFHpuJY6P@Mr0W3RTyV9Ylai0q1qykLjQ3V3hBAYgHtiCIDoajs3bhKlsz22WYMA7sCZdyQeXJAGsB3mA8dk7Szn5Dq0MXFeOuYIQRT6RpGRmHsZyI@bLdDmx8g/RgRivpHztFR/pYwvf1Zm2k3@1ZI1sT7Q@AY) - inspired by your comment to an answer of mine the other day.

Comment: @JayCe very nice and neat! Even using it with the precedence over `%*%` I see. :-) You can also put `\`:\`` as a function argument in case you wanted to use this in tandem with something else!

Comment: That's right - I always tend to forget about the backquotes.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>181</strike> <strike>138</strike> 136 bytes

Hopefully there will be a C compiler in the future to compile this! :-)

Thanks to Max Yekhlakov and ceilingcat for the suggestions.

```c
v,t,c,d;f(char*s){for(v=t=c=0;d=*s++;)t+=d==66?v=v*16+t,++c>2?v=!putchar(v),c=1:0,-t:d-65?d-79?d-68?d-85?0:3:4+t*3:2:1;putchar(v*16+t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNc8IgEL3nV1B7CSZ2/ExtUnTIeOGUE6dODw4xmplWO4I51PG3pxADCcZ6YIHl7du3b2CDLWPlc75nX6d0A965SPPDy25RFr7wmZ9Gmct262Ofw3N2OLoFEoihYZSiPve8CAoPpQgFwbJARX8UeML3PLYYy@vTz0moSreAPkOjcOgPRJgOgtkyHby@yRDMZZjPlsNwEk490Z@E43AUmaqKDUaXMt8L8L3O925xyFMIzg4ACgH4x2g4nn5G8q6URdl2I7jLfZ7/bg4ZkAc5yh4qRu72ehBmLoeRcyljsiIxXhEgD4lc@HpIdKZ1oCBOYuwoUFVVF8hFY1pFmXVMqnmuWKqdaqp6xwYlo6YwGJVT8bp0G6xVVLrvtkksEnW70je6sam4laAxVXuFbA3T7aSHTZQow9Cwa1/0m62tveN6YD1mY0HTm7b6J62dVh0bWywIMePTh8JIR1gS66bUYrkVQTpmWF/C2HhfEzEGEMtwjSD1cKT1a2yjsDUb7qizP0HS@WP/OUNbCNLSp3keZ/Af)

---

In case the C compiler of the future only understands BIBABOBU-ified ASCII :-)

```c
BIDUBIDOBOBODIBIDUBIDIBOBODIBIDOBUBUBADUBIDOBIDOBOBADIBIDOBUBIDOBADIBIDOBABIDUBOBOBADOBIDUBUBOBADABIDUBADUBIDOBIDOBIDOBODUBIDUBOBOBADIBIDUBIDOBUBODABIDUBIDIBUBODABIDOBUBUBODABUBIBUBADUBOBADOBIDUBUBUBADUBIDUBUBOBADUBOBADUBOBADABIDUBIDIBOBADUBUBODABOBADOBIDUBUBUBODABUBODABUBIDOBUBIDOBUBODUBIDUBIDOBUBODABIDUBIDOBOBADOBUBABUBIDOBOBADUBIDUBIDIBOBODIBOBADUBOBADUBIDOBUBUBODOBUBOBUBODUBIDUBIDOBUBODABOBABIDUBIBIDUBIDABIDUBIDIBIDOBUBIDOBADIBIDOBABIDUBOBOBADIBIDUBIDOBOBADABOBODIBIDOBUBUBODABUBABUBADOBUBIBOBODIBOBODABIDUBIDIBUBADOBOBADOBIDUBUBOBODABUBIDOBUBIDABUBODUBOBADOBIDUBUBOBODABUBIDUBUBADABUBODUBOBADOBIDUBUBOBODABUBIDOBUBADIBUBODUBOBADOBIDUBUBOBODABUBADIBUBIDABUBODUBUBIBUBADOBUBUBUBADOBUBIDIBOBADUBIDUBIDIBOBADOBUBUBUBADOBUBOBUBADOBUBABUBADUBIDUBIBIDUBIDABIDUBIDIBIDOBUBIDOBADIBIDOBABIDUBOBOBADIBIDUBIDOBOBADOBUBABUBIDOBOBADUBIDUBIDIBOBADABUBADUBIDUBODA
```

(Encoder [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLbsIwELzzFSZthO04zYPEpXENam899dRT4IBMEoxoQNjkUMS3p@tUrapWllazu57R7KiwUaq/0a3anzcVejR2ow932/no9@ik2wZmvWY7pkSN1XZ9ooZc6sMJCy2pCQJBXKNkKlQYCk1lwslO6ijhfsLZERRsjb1nf3qrfHhekNMx3kUZYVAWfFZwzryXp9c3r9z52WrAAKMsTFZEXHvgo/e1brED61OjmDOBKAXcEXQZITQMTJnm@UpAq2vs/s0TggbUlU4JFtXeVGiwXjeVNdgwoz@qQ40NYe78logBH8@w9DzypY5QFIGkKSGOfdXCB3Am5WTZTgj6M50s44kYON@H@6ZAHkNmMHAdXfuO2X9RdtJKJWNBjYBEiQ0gWSk5X3SyowkPLAsCNU@hHYM3x8QdYUomRcxCW1AT8nwB9f7BVT5zdZYv4mJaZIGl0yItEvHDHBQh2k8))

Comment: 179 bytes - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBLi8IwEP43ZcZk2dYVWejmkNoecsqpCBUPEtQWsg/Eha3S396dNLZWRA@ZMPM95kvMy96Yti255TU3/LRai3PE33jIp028ADxXOwAj9tujKTcHiBA/Qtz@VUfIADFulkQhGlEtE6cVmCCa4utsTVDm1TVjWMDPrzcoJ9GcWacsCC6FFbUI4@ZzU31Rv/s@QAEL57wEK0KMiYEZBRDz9yBwM8bsZOb0bZuoVCWSqk40HdUdlVClO09k2mN51yvqPeZ5V8zr9YWV37io9H6Dv2WHe9VV57DHmdRlnxwxx/tUl1oPPD1k9jt6Rf82eZfOJdKD3@1Ln/1MPmKoUb7e5/lE/gM "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Suggest `c=printf(&v),v=0` instead of `v=!putchar(v),c=1`

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>131</s> 128 bytes

```javascript
s=>unescape(s.replace(/B.(D.)?/g,(f,s)=>(-~g(f[1])*4*!!s+g((s||f)[1])).toString(16),g=c=>'IAOU'.search(c)).replace(/../g,'%$&'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJBb4MgFL7vX7TZJnSWpsmyS6MLphdOHBZOyw6Goeti1Ijbqdlfd2AFoVYPgDy/977vfbzv9DeVvDnV7basPkWXRZ2M4p9SSJ7WAkjUiLpIuQC7BIEjgq@7PARZKGEUg@1fDrL3/QfcPG9WK/mUAyDP5wzqEERt9dY2pzIH@xcY5hGP4oBgygIkRdrwL8AVxhZHSNUNHu4fAwi7A69KWRUCFZUiAOuEHLFaRC06fLOE9buKriG8m8lgTgZN6FCBDTdzYotSu6lqMTqm98syzBqLZ5hJgj2tIzP16urbhXHsDtuMa1UG0yvSSKe/eSbjA9V6baWRxbho/vka3RMPXhgHRndGDczRQZ2T9YyLjnlZxDrDFrWSiVaaGB3Mq3Kti0z88WbKOnxbE7GeEO8tDIIM/RJnxnzvsNcbnqjz54NOJnLOGeYgiKPP1FmO6Pc5dP8) Link includes test cases. Alternative version, also 131 bytes:

```javascript
s=>unescape(s.replace(/B.(D.)?/g,s=>(-~g(s[1])*4*!!s[3]+g(s[3]||s[1])).toString(16),g=c=>'IAOU'.search(c)).replace(/../g,'%$&'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJBb4MgFL7vX7TZJnQtTdNll8YumF44cVg4NR4Mo66LUSNup2Z/3YEVhFo9APL83ve@9/G@k99E8upc1qu8@BTNKWxkuP/JheRJKYBElSizhAuwjhA4IPi@TpcKAFZ/KZDHTQwXr4vZTB638YsObOPLpQ1DVBcfdXXOU7B5g8s05OE@IJiyAEmRVPwLcIWx5Agp3uDp8TmAsNnxIpdFJlBWpOAE5hE5YLWIWrT7ZhFrdxWdQ/gwksGcDBrRjoF1N3Nii1K7YbUYHdP7dZnKGotHKpMIe1r7ytTj1bdrxb47bDNuVRlMq0gjnf7GKxkfqNZrmfoqxkXzz9fonrjzwjjQu9NrYI4O6pysrTjpmJdFrDNsUisZaKWR0cE8lltdZOCPN1PW4fuaiPWEeG9hEKTrlzgz5nuHvd7wQJ0/H3QwkWPOMAdBHH2GZzqi32fX/AM) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saves 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.

Comment: Using `unescape()` is a nice idea.

Comment: `indexOf` -> `search` to save a byte.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you need to assign the RegEx to `r`.

Comment: @Shaggy Whoops, that's a left-over from a previous iteration. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 305 bytes

Well, I'm pretty sure this can be golfed out. But still, it exists. Takes input lowercase. `f` prints out the result in stdout.

EDIT: -8 chars thanks to me not being dumb anymore (spaces);
-13 chars thanks to crater2150

```scala
var k=Seq("bi","ba","bo","bu")
k++=k.init.flatMap(a=>Seq("di","da","do","du").map(a+_))//Putting "bu" here instead of at line 1, and in place of using init, would be interesting... if it did not cause a typing problem
var m=Seq[String]()
def g(a:Seq[String],b:Int)=k.indexOf(a(b)).toHexString
def f(a:String){a.split('b').drop(1).foreach(x=>m:+="b"+x)
var i=0
while(i<m.length){print(Integer.parseInt(g(m,i)+g(m,i+1),16).toChar)
i+=2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNb4IwGL73VxAutoHUucMOZpiAmqzJHAflsmVZihTo5GvQTRLjb3dt8YPFzEPf5u37fLXQrGlGD2X4ydbCWFBeGKwVrIgaw62q3eGH1sbGWbIvaIbctM2QqlKq8m0isLEsZ4N5wQWOMyoWtILUmWh4pOCRgkcKHkk4ztXc@kAIKN1c6b4tRc2L5B0iELHYSCAd907tcEwKgbRHxFo/hhSGCGFRPrG2w2harGi6RTuKmyrjAg7CAcJRXVZwhHBc1oyuU9g6k3xsOWZoWm2Xgjt3YJvyjEH@mOOMFYlI0a6SWgJKb5awGle0bphsYAJzmyNLb9YI2aMHlWWa0hoBbjn3@/1hOFzNlyvj1X@ZAxBD0yMz4rmy@p4vF9GLeLLKPfDc2WkW6J7Ivpt1uMus4/tHVPBHhcyuHbrd1fOOdeGp2f@ZyNHP7SH7fkSn9s84/5y58zgxTndzr9KpRP5Z7@9Nb71M0EOQXr6Tzu0T15Qf67ncsnpKGwblbwjA/vAL)

Comment: You can replace `dropRight(1)` with `init`, `Seq("").drop(1)` with `Seq[String]()`, and `map(b=>a+b)` with `map(a+_)`

Comment: @crater2150 thanks! my compiler did not want `map(a+_)` to work but I knew I could do that. thanks for other tips!

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + common Linux utilities, 75 bytes

```bash
sed $(printf `printf %s s/{B{O,A,I}D,B}{U,O,A,I}/%x/g\;` {15..0})|xxd -r -p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVI7D4IwEN79FR0k0YSHDk5O17Dc1Ok2BzT4WowRBxLktyOFPqkah/ZS@t33OHrYV5euq44lmy/uj@vteWKFqlHFqqzhjYghxjaPedtQPB6yqM7Ou23BmvUmTVft8lXXJUseLLl3HcccOfQLc9EvGKpQZ1uJCw4zBaCPYDLQsYJB9bvqcumQy31c8pYUdpD515M8jfRg6MF0TC1ozCAvkU6YUEmHFdKUYbDspLr1ne/NraAC65h2BFabHH3hVBoU7Vg8CJr49NMYBsYE16LksUxNYDAMHcL@z@@e0AwAvYFrBKpw6Lwaf1DgZYPAnf8IRPDGvk2GHAQ6/jTP7y/wBg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>142</s> <s>139</s> <s>127</s> 118 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(chr(16*a+b)for a,b in zip(*[iter(4*F(l[:-2])+F(l[-1])-1for l in s.split('B')[1:])]*2));F=' IAOU'.find
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVI9b4MwEN3zK1AWbFKQQFUHqgy2okg3efJEGUhTFFcUELC0f55iwMYONOpgH4bnex9c/d3dqjLq8@NbX2Rfl2vmtLHrBp@VKNH7rUHhi5cdLjivGid7ujiidH5EjbxEdB8NevbOqEhiP0rxQT75YYr9UGILiWyDti5Eh1zq4iSMU5x6Ecav56PrAGHcDXJRXvu6EWXn5GhP4QSUDAtObFhkrGw@L5VTRske73bmRTJeXi5yysd9eLsF5ZscXDNMlWjUsKt2hgqgcp@WoiRb6v5rS54mqsUP0Tfu5SjMKEUiDWNrJmWcSYG6w9Jd5aW@2drMSmbzyvISx8LNDX5mVD4ybkdkwUFHwR@KhJVIRpUAbnW5FwSrYKyx0ZFuawIdBljhKwTMRsGYJjs0YnkjK3X2QLDV7P2VDDcQYOhTfR6/GX5M/ws)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

```python
lambda w:''.join('c60238e4d1_b7f95a'[hash(x)%3046%17]for x in w.split('B')[1:]).decode('hex')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLjoIwFN3PVxATU9gQUUdnTGbRZjZ31VVXjpmgQMAoECWR@XqmRW5pQV30yek9D275V6VFPm@Sr5/mFJ73UejcNoT4xyLLXXJYzeaLj3gZBb/7dfL5HpJtGl5Tt/ami9lyNQ3Wu6S4OLWT5c7Nv5anrHIJI9422Ow8P4oPRRS7JI1r4jXlJcsrJ3EnDL6pHCAH7/aCiXaWtxPvbYgUBpIz3r0U3QlXqlFyxmoao@7UfB/IqLB0wAiMWtp6Rm7VU6c7U@@G6hdDNYhplSik4WvMhL650qcr9NUxLfxmazNX2nlHx30aPbcw@LmxipbxYUIWGnQS4qVGGGnkDPmFVWWoB0a5WD2jE32sCXQWYGWPCOh8gtFLdmbU8kZH6ux@4KPOe5aMMBBg6MM6r2/kf2n@AQ)

Comment: I love answers that abuse the hash value of sufficiently small lists

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>86</s> 75 bytes

```ruby
->s{[s.gsub(/B[^B]+/){|x|"546798ABDCEF1023"[x.to_i(31)/7%38%20]}].pack'H*'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNS8NAEL33V5SF0taPpG3U1oPCrFGc0572tKSlFSoiYnAtVJL89piv3cw2tXjYGXbz8t6bx3ztNj/59i6/vNeJ0t6r3m1GPldLHp374yTdp@z66mZ@uwAePjw@TSezgKm99/25ehsF07E/HwSLwWwSZZEXr1/eh89nwyxXjGOIHIqDoSgOVF0097ZLLjiwiz5rMBQvuaxq8UoQ8iijtHx1B4sqqmEhmsjLWh@jBMTLf72Xt1qhdQ/2j0MXBlM5KJFknq6SmVeUvixDy27SMd9cb7RDM7OZtE2h1ZZEX5AuK0UnGQeFNgF50ht2vAludKXDcugDO3k4u2GTPO4JbQboZG4Q2MyHZHfcrMCZDTru3D0QnU37KxlJEEj8GZ7TL8Ai72MdJ6lOe3F/q3TUy/Jf)

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, <s>74</s> 72 bytes

Beginner level solution in Dyalog APL (just started learning this a couple of days ago!).  Defines a dfn that takes one right argument (the input).  72 characters, 72 bytes when using the dyalog encoding.  Based on Emigna's solution in 05AB1E .

```
{⎕UCS 16⊥¨(1 0⍴⍨≢t)⊂1-⍨(,('B',('B'∘.,'IAO'),¨'D')∘.,'IAOU')⍳t←('B'⍷⍵)⊂⍵}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and to the world of APL golfing. This is amazing after only a couple of days of learning APL. You may enjoy [the APL golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl). Feel free to participate in [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) too!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 bytes

```
®+“IAO”+”D®;p“IAOU”Ẏ€
=”B©œṗµḊ¢iⱮ’s2ḅ⁴Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QOu1HDXM8Hf0fNcwFsua6HFpnXQARCQVyH@7qe9S0hssWyHQ6tPLo5Ic7px/a@nBH16FFmY82rnvUMLPY6OGO1keNWx7u7vn//7@Tp4unkyOQ9HfyB2JPMPZ0ApJAOtTJ0QUmFwrmewL5EDmIOoQcRL8/VFUoiimeLpg2QGhHsDxEF0IfSA63mzyh9jkiqUS2zxPsan@4On@4myF2wHTA/OaI4TqQi/zh5qH6FF/IhCKp8ERyH8wc/CKOAA)

The technique used is very similar to [Emigna's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171401/59487). I will golf this further soon, hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ć¡Ç1^9%4%εDg≠i421øP]€OžvβžzвçJ
```

Port of [*@Dennis*' insane Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171415/52210) (just with less convenient builtins). So make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SPuhhYfbDeMsVU1Uz211SX/UuSDTxMjw8I6A2EdNa/yP7is7t@novqoLmw4v9/r/38nTxdPJEUj6O/kDsScYezoBSSAd6uToApMLBfM9gXyIHEQdQg6i3x@qKhTFFE8XTBsgtCNYHqILoQ8kh9tNnlD7HJFUItvnCXa1P1ydP9zNEDtgOmB@c8RwHchF/nDzUH2KL2RCkVR4IrkPZg5@EUcA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##fVKxDgFBEO19hkQnEqJRzkUzmtGsjoRERKWQSIhKc/EXVBqVRKJSOFrxDX7k3J6d3R2LYndvZ9@99@ZlJtP@YDxMl7N5Mb3Gl20SV3uNUr10PzZHz/VmXK9Vk1O7@1zt6Xae3Q@38@JxSHattFjplNMIm5AtzBaZbxWpfM@qBVtyzxSRgStz4xMsKtuZwmJ0Te/vxTIaC4UcCMKFkyFBom9veucb7B@fFhiTy2uk10yoxM2SNmUZHDvnwm/Sm3@CaZjbdBE4beXpk3eqXNHFIiBo21d/jWFgjCIWVYLl0wQGYYiRsDF@94Q2ABSBMwJNc@hNjQwKRG8QuJNDQMGM/UpGeQj0/DHP/wq8AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ć¡             # Split the input-string on its first character ('B')
               #  i.e. "BIDABIDIBIDOBIDABIDUBUBIDUBIDI"
               #   → ["IDA","IDI","IDO","IDA","IDU","U","IDU","IDI"]
  Ç            # Convert each character to it's ordinal value
               #  → [[73,68,65],[73,68,73],[73,68,79],[73,68,65],[73,68,85],85,[73,68,85],[73,68,73]]
   1^          # XOR it by 1
               #  → [[72,69,64],[72,69,72],[72,69,78],[72,69,64],[72,69,84],84,[72,69,84],[72,69,72]]
     9%        # Take modulo-9
               #  → [[0,6,1],[0,6,0],[0,6,6],[0,6,1],[0,6,3],3,[0,6,3],[0,6,0]]
       4%      # Take Modulo-4
               #  → [[0,2,1],[0,2,0],[0,2,2],[0,2,1],[0,2,3],3,[0,2,3],[0,2,0]]
ε         ]    # Now map it to:
 Dg≠i          # If the length is not 1:
               #  i.e. [0,2,1] → 3 → 1 (truthy)
               #  i.e. 3 → 1 → 0 (falsey)
     421øP     # Multiply the first number by 4, second by 2, and third by 1
               #  i.e. [0,2,1] and [4,2,1] → [[0,4],[2,2],[1,1]] → [0,4,1]
           €O  # Then sum every inner list
               #  [[0,4,1],[0,4,0],[0,4,2],[0,4,1],[0,4,3],3,[0,4,3],[0,4,0]]
               #   → [5,4,6,5,7,3,7,4]
žvβ            # Convert this list from base-16 to base-10
               #  → 1415934836
   žzв         # Convert this integer from base-10 to base-256
               #  → [84,101,115,116]
      ç        # Convert this number to ASCII characters
               #  → ["T","e","s","t"]
       J       # Join the characters together (and output implicitly)
               #  → "Test"
```

Comment: Wondered how you snipped 3 off emignas score. Jeebus this is complex +1 for the effort on the port-- never used XOR or that base conversion before! Will keep in mind from now on!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yeah, Dennis' answer is something I would have never came up with myself.. And in Jelly this is done way more efficient, since his answer is 15 bytes and mine is 30. Just figured it was worth posting as well however, even though it's a port. I've only used XOR once myself, and Base conversion pretty often.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 178 bytes

```
{(([((((()()()()){}){}){}()){}]{}){{}<>(({}){}){}(<>)}{}<({}(<>))(<>)((()()()())({})()){{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}<>({}<>)<>{}}{}><>{}{})<>}<>([]){{}({}(((({}){}){}){}){}<>)<>([])}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU47DsMgDL2OPeQGERIoC1MmpihDWqlS1apDV8TZ6bOdBKImgP3w@3D7bs/P8Hhvr1oz0ULysf2ciy1tV2lzGR3ReT86Lrgia1mOTi48kWZVcMa5EK88OojESNyAAHJxUkHDEJNllSzxpRZnSyVCQFdriFMMHjtOM7bXOu@41RQMgbOzbOJPhT8drhxRKlN74/wnGdaU0Byae9rVx@z6tr56S1R@6l4fu@zU5c9dTZoIjzrcfw)

#### Explanation

```
# Step 1: convert to hex.
# For each pair of letters in the input:
{

  (

    # Compare first letter to B
    ([((((()()()()){}){}){}()){}]{})

    # If not B, pop previous output, multiply by 4, and put on third stack.
    # 4 is added automatically from pushing/popping the difference
    # between the letters B and D.
    {{}<>(({}){}){}(<>)}{}

    <

      # Push second letter in pair to other stack
      ({}(<>))

      # Push 4 and 9
      (<>)((()()()())({})())

      # Compute 3-((8-(n mod 9)) mod 4)
      # (same as (n-1) mod 9 mod 4)
      {{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}<>({}<>)<>{}}{}

    >

    # Add result to third stack (either 0 or 4*previous+4)
    <>{}{}

  # Push onto second stack
  )

<>}

# Step 2: Pair up hex digits.
# While digits remain on right stack:
<>([]){{}

  # Push top of stack + 16*second on stack to left stack
  ({}(((({}){}){}){}){}<>)<>

([])}

# Switch to left stack for output.
<>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 199 bytes

```java
s->{var z="";for(var x:s.substring(1).split("B")){int d=-1;for(var y:x.split("D"))d=-~d*4+"IAOU".indexOf(y);z+=(char)(d>9?d+55:d+48);}return new String(new java.math.BigInteger(z,16).toByteArray());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNj5swFLznV1iczCaxFGm3akNJZRRV8qHisPJp1YM3kKxTAsg2aUiU/vXUGMzHkq56sB/G43nzBj/27Mjm@@jXjR/yTCiw12tUKJ6gbZFuFM9S9OBNNgmTEvxgPAWXCQB58ZrwDZCKKR2OGY/AQe/BZyV4unv5CZjYSddAAfje8Hytd2d1WIEt8G9yvrocmQBn33G8bSZgtTgtJZLFqzQ4uHCRzBOuoBM4rnvhqQKRP1@06HJ5soC1Bui9P9HD49QhOKQO4mkUn8ItLF3vPPXh5o0JF0arL9@i6dPTMpo@fna9q4hVIVKQxr9BLQ5Wj8aJA1NvKOA7kqp4Fwt4ni0@uUhlQaliLAQroasJbp6ptC1fxVJJ4DcGAOAEZE0CrAdZh3pgE8Nm3UUahAF2Zr1T2JzsTtGAmlm/HeHoXXbactcRtyg9W65efhJUcz1sPjzS9b/VVKs6T1cJbk@812IxRkeF7FU1zmSrDit1LUPHbp2ye0Nt/Yibym29nRddbtrLH/YiNRnv@DPAktYH@qFCMlIYBjY7HbC8V0NGrgxuS@vnfU2kdYIMnLcI0lRJevdo6Bge1IZH6oa3IRzdun85Q3sI0tNneT5@gx3zUa51g1b/jLpJTYsu60Z12z59LqWKDygrFMo1SiUp3CKW50kJK6Ru9ZptUo3r7S8)

### Credits

- -2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

Comment: Could you use `-~d` instead of `(d+1)`?

Comment: Yep, thanks! I had those in my first version, then I toyed with the idea of using `char`s instead and when I came back to my first version, I totally forgot it again. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**VBA (Excel), with an *amazing* <s>322</s> 244 bytes**

Yeah, and I *LOVE* hexadecimal. (There's no sarcasm font yet, so I'm using italics for now) <s>I'll add comments if someone wants, but I think it's self explanatory.</s> Golfing happened.

```vb
Sub b(s)
For Each c In Split(Replace(s,"D",""),"B")
c=Application.Match(c,Array("I","A","O","U","II","IA","IO","IU","AI","AA","AO","AU","IO","OA","OO","OU"),0)
If Not IsError(c)Then d=d &c-1:If Len(d)=2Then e=e &Chr("&h"&d):d=""
Next
Debug.?e
End Sub
```

With Comments:

```vb
Sub b(s)
  'For each string between B's (Remove the D's first)
  For Each c In Split(Replace(s,"D",""),"B")
    'Get the index of the element in the array (Can cause error if empty)
    c = Application.Match (c,Array("I","A","O","U","II","IA","IO","IU","AI","AA","AO","AU","IO","OA","OO","OU"),0)
    'If c isn't an error
    If Not IsError(c) Then
      'Subtract 1 from c and add to d  --> Array index is 1 based
      d = d & (c-1)
      'If d is 2 characters
      If Len(d)=2 Then
        'Add the char from the hex value of d   --> &h forces Hex
        e = e & Chr("&h" & d)
        'Reset d
        d = ""
      End if
    End if
  Next
  'Print the output
  Debug.Print e
End Sub
```

I really tried to get this into the VB Immediate Window, but it doesn't seem to work there... that would cut 11 characters I think. I also wanted to put the Match statement into brackets, but that causes a silent error everytime. Help is appreciated :D

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks! I've been here for a while, just never been able to post anything :)

Comment: `Array("I","A","O","U","II","IA","IO","IU","AI","AA","AO","AU","IO","OA","OO","OU")` -> 
`Split("I A O U II IA IO IU AI AA AO AU IO OA OO OU")` and `Not IsError(c)` -> `IsError(c)=0`

Answer (score 1):

## [Haxe](https://haxe.org), 228 bytes

```
s->{var l=(u,i)->((i=u.charCodeAt(i))&8==8?0:1)|((i>>1)&2),p=s.split("B"),i=-1,q,o;[while((i+=2)<p.length)String.fromCharCode(l(q=p[i+1],o=q.length-1)+((o>1?l(q,0)+1:0)+((l(q=p[i],o=q.length-1)+o*(l(q,0)+1)*2)*4))*4)].join("");}
```

Not the best, standard library function names are too large :(

[Try it online!](http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#188Af)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 35 bytes

```
mCid16cm+4imx"IAOU"k.[N2d4tc-Q\D\B2
```

Outputs as a list of characters.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mCid16cm%2B4imx%22IAOU%22k.%5BN2d4tc-Q%5CD%5CB2&input=%22BIDIBADIBIDOBIDABIDOBODIBIDOBODIBIDOBODUBOBA%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
mCid16cm+4imx"IAOU"k.[N2d4tc-Q\D\B2
                          tc-Q\D\B   Get the vowels associated with each digit.
       m            .[N2d            Pad with a quote.
           mx"IAOU"k                 Find each character's position.
        +4i              4           Convert to base 4 and add 4.
      c                           2  Split the result into pairs.
mCid16                               Get the associated ASCII characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
ＦＳ≡ιB⊞υ⁰D⊞υ×⁴⊕⊟υ⊞υ⁺⊟υ⊕⌕AOUι⭆⪪υ²℅↨ι¹⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBNS8QwEL3vrwg9TaCCinhwT4lFmIOksPYHhDRrA922tIkexN9e06afLG5gJmTeezNvogrZqlqWfX@uWwJYNc6ebGuqT6CUdN/GqoKAoeTnoGSnScSjF5K6rgAXk3t6nKrJpvphLrqDp5hgpVp90ZXVOaR1A476czzk@ixdaVdBWrpuIuxFb6bKIWIii2Jigvj3kHpzFoLHd9nAqSmNHdo8evWrX0cqq1vg3heYmDw801HZ9xwT5MxnwYUPHAO5z/7OOEtmLBvf6N8BC7wVC3oxsbJdF0yuJ4SbjXhQrboB@98TTvPYhrmdh6NrsfDE4jnMmBXzbuzK3eBILP32m976mWzDwI2/uc/tCuvvvso/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ≡ι
```

Loop over each input character and switch.

```
B⊞υ⁰
```

If it's a `B` then push `0` to the predefined empty list.

```
D⊞υ×⁴⊕⊟υ
```

If it's a `D` then pop the last value, increment it, multiply by `4`, and push it again.

```
⊞υ⁺⊟υ⊕⌕AOUι
```

Otherwise, find the index in the string `AOU`, increment it, and add to the last value.

```
⭆⪪υ²℅↨ι¹⁶
```

Split the list into pairs of values, decode as base 16, convert to ASCII, and implicitly print.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>145</s> 134 bytes

```
import StdEnv                   // import things like addition and comparison
?c=(743rem(toInt c))/16         // magical formula that maps ['IAOU'] to [0,1,2,3]
@[_,b,'D',d:t]=[?d+ ?b*4+4: @t] // convert B#D#
@[_,b:t]=[?b: @t]               // convert "B#"
@_=[]                           // handle base case
$[u,v:t]=[u<<4+v: $t]           // turn the digits into 2-digit numbers
$e=e                            // handle base case
```

```
toString o$o@                   // convert to string (make numbers (make digits))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFda4MwFIbv/RWBCbbTMcakA2nwA3cRGORCvBIpGm0RNBkahf35Zanxq5T1Igk5z3vOeZND6jKjomFFX5egySoqquabtRxEvPikg@YSuPuw39uy2XGGKAdkv399O2hecrJyywgNq3B4ChO3MIGbP9um7QCPp4orkk@RE0xSTU96axjj/fFom4MDdMn0EpYi4lnLtSfQ8baiFwBBYgQoRIEvdxxgudC4UCB3ecaBH84sHu9I3hVTupWpfDyp4psqKLzvoE5/5Cprzbuy/z2hqZ@/UW77odE1XnR48ax6zBnz2/w7d1dHeKl3@9JHPxNvFGjjb67zOOIbqZzNuaeEV4zK6XAWqUExnXkaXJGan/gl5zq7dOIFfYnwh2ZNRbo/)

Explained:

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 119 bytes

```php
foreach(explode(B,$argn)as$i=>$m)($v=$v*16+4*strpos(XIAO,$m[-3]?:B)+strpos(IAOU,$m[-1]?:B))?$i&1||print chr($v&=255):0;
```

assumes uppercase input. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d554d2d5d0c5a9b5b59e5c61dd6ac3afea7db227).

requires PHP 7.1
for older PHP, use `substr($m,-3,1)` and `substr($m,-1)` instead of `$m[-<x>]` (+16 bytes);
for younger PHP, put `B`, `XIAO` and `IAOU` in quotes to avoid warning messages (+10 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 40 bytes

```
'B"IAOU"©âÐUs'D®ââJ)˜sXíDεSðý}:#khJ2ôHçJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3UnJ09E/VOnQysOLDk8ILVZ3ObQOyFrkpXl6TnHE4bUu57YGH95weG@tlXJ2hpfR4S0eh5d7/f/v5Oni6eQIxJ4u/kDsCKb9oXwEHeoE4QHVQFVBZBzhOhzhJqCqAekEqwSzIWowbYLwwbY4IUxAmB4K1Q2TQ3UbMu0IsRGsPhTJ9Z5Idoci2e@PRIeCbQSaAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 163 bytes

```
function f($s){$t=[I=>0,A=>1,O=>2,U=>3];for($q=explode(B,$s);$a=&$q[++$i];){$a=($a[1]?($t[$a[0]]+1)*4:0)+$t[$a[2*($a[1]==D)]];$i%2?:print(chr(($q[$i-1]<<4)+$a));}}
```

Call `f(string $s)` with the appropriate string of bibabobu-encoded characters, and it will print the decoded string.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 199 bytes

```python
import re
lambda s:''.join(eval(re.sub(r'(\d+), (\d+)',r'chr(16*\1+\2)',str(eval(s.replace('I','1').replace('A','2').replace('O','3').replace('U','4').replace('B',',-1+').replace('D','*4+')[1:])))))
```

Not the shortest but without loops.